# Magento 2: configurable product doesn't update image on select of attribute

Tags: magento2, product, swatches

I know this is probably a **duplicated**, but I read **ALL** the posts about this issue and I still didn't figure it out.

So, I have attribute `size` (dropdown) and attribute `color` (swatches). What I want is to change the picture based on the selection of the attributes.

The result is that Magento loads me the default picture.

I cleared the cache and I did a re-index, but the problem still persists.

Any suggestions?

Here is the screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnAPt.jpg

Here is the configuration I have on the back-end

https://i.stack.imgur.com/154Mc.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVTyW.jpg

Here is the error that I got:

```
TypeError: this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes is undefined swatch-renderer.js:772:29
    _getAttributeCodeById https://webiste.com/pub/static/version1576523586/frontend/Mgs/amely/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:772
    $.widget/</proxiedPrototype[prop]</< jQuery
    _OnClick https://webiste.com/pub/static/version1576523586/frontend/Mgs/amely/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:738
    $.widget/</proxiedPrototype[prop]</< jQuery
    _EventListener https://webiste.com/pub/static/version1576523586/frontend/Mgs/amely/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js:640
    jQuery 2
```

PS, I'm using `Magento 2.3.3`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please write all the configuration you have done.

Comment: just updated my answer

Comment: you have to add different images for you simple products of configurable product then it will appear on your selection

Comment: well, that's what I did. All the products have different pictures

Comment: any suggestions? Please!

Comment: it's default feature of magento, you just need to configure it properly!

Comment: Well, sadly is not that easy in my case. I'm getting a js error once I click on the product. everything is set up properly

Comment: then you should post error here then can find some solution.

Comment: I updated my answer. Thanks.

Comment: it clearly seems that your attribute "mappedAttributes" is not defined. please assign value to that attribute

Comment: lol, and what value should I put? This is the standard file of magento